# Error building openjdk9

Tags: java

I've just cloned openjdk9:

```
> hg clone http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev 9dev
> cd 9dev
> sh get_source.sh
> bash configure
> make
```

Now I want to build it but gives me this error after "make":

```
Compiling 457 files for BUILD_INTERIM_jdk.javadoc
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Compiling 159 files for BUILD_TOOLS_JDK
-Xbootclasspath/p is no longer a supported option.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
CompileTools.gmk:45: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "/home/edoardo/Scrivania/Tesi/9dev/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-release/buildtools/jdk_tools_classes/_the.BUILD_TOOLS_JDK_batch" non riuscito
make/Main.gmk:85: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "buildtools-jdk" non riuscito
make[3]: *** [/home/edoardo/Scrivania/Tesi/9dev/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-release/buildtools/jdk_tools_classes/_the.BUILD_TOOLS_JDK_batch] Errore 1
make[2]: *** [buildtools-jdk] Errore 1
make[2]: *** Attesa per i processi non terminati....
```

This is the output of the error:

```
ERROR: Build failed for target 'default (exploded-image)' in configuration 'linux-x86_64-normal-server-release' (exit code 141) 

=== Output from failing command(s) repeated here ===
* For target buildtools_jdk_tools_classes__the.BUILD_TOOLS_JDK_batch:
-Xbootclasspath/p is no longer a supported option.
rror: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

* All command lines available in /home/edoardo/Scrivania/Tesi/9dev/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-release/make-support/failure-logs.
=== End of repeated output ===

No indication of failed target found.
Hint: Try searching the build log for '] Error'.
Hint: If caused by a warning, try configure --disable-warnings-as-errors.

/home/edoardo/Scrivania/Tesi/9dev/make/Init.gmk:291: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "main" non riuscito
make[1]: *** [main] Errore 1
/home/edoardo/Scrivania/Tesi/9dev/make/Init.gmk:185: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "default" non riuscito
make: *** [default] Interruzione
```

What's going wrong? Why?

Comment: Where did you get the build steps from? Because the one at _9dev/common/doc/building.md_ tells you to use `make images`.

Comment: What's your bootstrap JDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved not only running `make clean` but also deleting directly the folder "build"